# Execute Ex command inside expression register

Tags: expression-register

Executing `:echo 'hello'` prints "hello". Executing `"=echo 'hello'<cr>p` however, results in multiple errors.

Is there a way to execute Ex commands inside of the expression register?

Comment: What are you trying to do? From `:help quote_=`, "the expression must evaluate to a String". `echo` does not return a String, it prints a String.

Comment: @gdupras not quite: the expression register expects an _expression_ (`:help expr`), while `:echo` is a command.

Comment: @gdupras I was talking about executing an arbitrary command. `:echo` was just an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use a command `:echo` in place of an expression `:help expr`.

There is however a function (whose invocation is an `expr8` or `expr9`) that executes commands:

```
"=execute('echo "hello"')<CR>p
```

But in this case you probably just want

```
"='hello'<CR>p
```

since `'hello'` is an expression.